# How to force an Update without an API on iOS

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an iOS app and I need to force users to update to the latest version.

Is there an App Store Connect function to do this? The idea is to do this for the only time since we are going to implement a message like "There is a new version to be installed", the problem is that first we want everyone to be in the same version

Any answer is helpful. 
Thank you. My regards

Answer (score 0):

Without an api there is no Appstore fuction
But you can still create one

Request parameters:

`int appVersion`

Response

```
boolean forceUpgrade
boolean recommendUpgrade
```

If `forceUpgrade` is `true`, show a popup dialog with options to either let user quit the app

Else if `recommendUpgrade` is `true`, show the pop-up dialog with options to update or to continue using the app.

Comment: Ok, but this would only affect new versions and the old versions would not have this functionality, right? Thank you for your answer!!

Comment: yes there is now ways to force upgrade old versions  Or you can try refuse their acces to the server in function of their version and redirect them to the appstore page to update the app , but idk if your app is only online